# How to display grand total only and not subtotals in a matrix in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is any chance simply display Grand Total in matrix and not display subtotals for each column?

[image]

as a value I am using a measure :

```
Total Premium = CALCULATE(SUM(fact_Premium[Premium]))
```

I only need a number 44,025,328.

I saw that it is possible  in a Table. But is any trick to do that in Matrix?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you can do that with the GUI like for a table, but it's possible to modify your DAX a bit using `ISFILTERED` or `HASONEVALUE` type of functions.

Something like this, for example:

```
Total Premium =
VAR Prem = CALCULATE(SUM(fact_Premium[Premium]))
RETURN IF(NOT(HASONEVALUE(Dates[Year])) && HASONEVALUE(Dates[Month]),
          BLANK(),
          Prem
       )
```

Comment: Thank you . It works for Written Premium. Gives me some trouble with Earned. Probably because of relationship I have